# how to move focus from html popup to textfield in flex parent

Tags: apache-flex, textbox, focus

I have a flex component embedded in an HTML page. The flex component has a text box. A timer runs in flex which makes an external interface call after every 10 mins. This would in turn open a popup using HTML (window.open). 
My problem is that when I am typing in the text box and the popup is displayed, I lose the focus from the text box. Is it possible that the popup will be displayed and i lI also be able to continue typing without any break or having to click on the text box again for regaining focus.

Comment: Why don't you open a pop-up in Flex, then you won't have to deal with JavaScript

Comment: I want the popup to be an indicator to the user, such that even when he has minimized the main window and the timer completes 10 mins, the popup will open.